# Vectorize Reading MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I currently read mongoDB into my python function using pymongo.

```
db_client = MongoClient('url/to/Mongo')
db = db_client.db_name

data = list(db.collection.find({'query.name':{'$regex':"Beginning_of_Name*"}},{'data'}))
```

While the building the Cursor is quick, it takes time to convert to a list. Is there a way to speed this up?

I've tried to build it directly with numpy arrays but it just wraps the object in a numpy array. I was hoping that building directly into a numpy array would be able to vectorize it to speed up operations

Comment: It is almost certainly **not** the creation of a list that is computationly intensive in your example, but the query itself. The building of the list is basically constant time with respect to fetching all the *rows* (results) of the underlying query. Also note that a regex query does NOT use indexes

Answer (score 0):

The most possible solution, if not done already, would be to index the documents you want to query. This will trade-off memory on your DB with speed of the querys. Go to your terminal and write the following:

```
db.collection.createIndex({<field>:<1==Ascending><0=Descending>}
```

Look into https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/ for a more specific explanation according to your Use-Case.